# Date time cast preferred method

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, datetime

What would be the preferred method for speed and less database stress using a between or less than?

```
SELECT LogId
FROM [Master].[dbo].log mlog
WHERE cast(LogDate as Date) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
```

Or, would it be better to do this?

````
SET @StartLogId = (SELECT TOP 1 LogID
FROM [Master].[dbo].log mlog
WHERE LogDate >= '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000')

SET @EndLogId = (SELECT TOP 1 LogID
FROM [Master].[dbo].log mlog
WHERE LogDate < '2019-12-31T00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY LogDate DESC);

SELECT LogId
FROM [Master].[dbo].log mlog
WHERE mlog.LogId >= @StartLogId
    AND mlog.LogId <= @EndLogId;
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal preference is to never use `BETWEEN` since its not abundantly clear, *from the code itself*, whether the range includes `2019-01-01` and `2019-12-31`.  I realize one can easily check the manual to see how `BETWEEN` operates, but in my opinion, this is far more easily read, without any chance for confusion:

```
SELECT LogId
FROM [Master].[dbo].log mlog
WHERE cast(LogDate as Date) >= '2019-01-01' 
    AND cast(LogDate as Date) <= '2019-12-31'
```

Be aware, though, that `cast(LogDate as date)` is not an optimal way to perform this query.  The far better solution would be:

```
SELECT LogId
FROM [Master].[dbo].log mlog
WHERE LogDate >= '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000' 
    AND LogDate < '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000'
```

The above statement is SARGable, and will also ensure you get the range desired.  Comparing `<= '2019-12-31'` actually means *before December 31st, 2019*, when you probably actually mean up until the end-of-day on December 31st, 2019.  Looking for dates *less than* the start of the *next day* ensures you get all the rows between the start of the day on 2019-01-01 and the end of the day on 2019-12-31.

Note, I'm including a `T` between the date and time components; this indicates to SQL Server to treat the value as an [ISO8601 date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which will prevent possible errors that might be introduced under non-US English language installations.